# Spring+Hibernate mysql version problem?

Tags: mysql, hibernate, spring

I'm trying to deploy my spring mvc application under Fedora 10. The problem is , while I'm running app. on my local machine there is no problem, it's running perfect . I take my build in fedora and deploy it under tomcat . I can access site , but whenever I request any url that makes query in order to show or insert data (for example aa.jsp page list the employees in the db) I'm facing the problem , 
Data Access Failure ; could not execute query; SQL[ select this_id ad id5.0 ......].... org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammerException: could not execute query

There is one difference between my local machine and server machine  ,mysql version difference , my mysql is v5.1.36 other one is v5.0.84 . It becomes funny to me . Is there anyone can help me? I can not post the whole error becouse I'm devoloping offline and can't export them under online machine...Thanks,

Comment: Can you please provide the complete stack trace? All the stuff below org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammerException: could not execute query

Answer (score 0):

1. Use Hibernate logging (set categories `org.hibernate.SQL` and `org.hibernate.type` to TRACE) to get the prepared statement and the values being bound to the statement. Run the statement yourself with the given values in MySQL, and see what it says.
2. Show the full stack trace. You can get it there somehow.

Comment: how can I implement this , con you explain in detail

Comment: See the [ref guide on logging](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/session-configuration.html#configuration-logging). You can have Hibernate print out the SQL statement it's running along with the values it's plugging in to all the placeholders. You can take this query and run it manually in a SQL workbench to help diagnose the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using `MySQL5InnoDBDialect`, not `MySQLInnoDBDialect` as your dialect.